# Azure Devops Build Failed: No certificate found with the supplied thumbprint

Tags: xamarin, azure-devops, certificate, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have created a Xamarin project. The UWP project compiles on my PC, but fails in Azure DevOps with the following error:
Error : No certificate found with the supplied thumbprint: XXXXXXX

I have recreated the certificate and installed in on my local trusted root certificate store.
Am I missing a step somewhere?
do i need to register it somehow in DevOps?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a temporary singing file in the uwp project, but its probably getting excluded by the .gitignore file and not getting uploaded.

Update:  [This](https://yanxiaodi.medium.com/using-azure-devops-build-pipeline-for-xamarin-forms-436ddc6bcf97) article provides the details of how to setup the build in Azure DevOps and how to fix this signing issue.

Comment: Also i don't know if it matters i am not using Git but TFS storage

Comment: i don't think that would matter, if the file is there.  Something is happening during the build that is stopping it from seeing or accessing it.

Comment: it is sitting in the UWP folder. is that the right place for it?

Comment: I think this might help you fix it -> https://yanxiaodi.medium.com/using-azure-devops-build-pipeline-for-xamarin-forms-436ddc6bcf97.   If you look under the "Adjusting the tasks" section about halfway down, it explains how to resolve the issue your having.

Comment: i know i have not looked at this in a long time..... but i am looking into this again. i have followed the instructions in the link but am still getting the error.